# What does ‘business’ and ‘overlap’ mean in the following passage?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> The music and film industries in Hong Kong have a very close relationship. Celebrities in our city don’t stay in one genre. Film stars often release Cantopop albums, and Contopop stars often act in Hong Kong films. These **businesses overlap** more often than we can count.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*These businesses* refers to the two most popular entertainment industries in Hong Kong: Cantopop, which is just a contraction of Cantonese pop music, and films made and produced in Hong Kong. One of the meanings of the verb *overlap* is *to cover part of the same area of interest and responsibility*. So, *These businesses overlap* simply means that these two industries have lots of things in common. Cantopop singers play in Hong Kong films and Hong Kong movie stars sometimes sing Cantopop songs.

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at the facts.

- Some people work in the film industry.
- Some people work in the music industry
- Some people work in *both* industries

When people work in both industries, there is *overlap* between them, because the same people are at work.

Business is used here synonymous to industry.